# struts2 jquery autocompleter with runtime parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2, autocomplete, struts2-jquery-plugin

I'm trying to use Struts2 jQuery `autocompleter` tag.

Documentation is [here](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/AutocompleterTag).

A tag that is like:

```
<s:url var="remoteurl" action="jsonlanguages"/>
<sj:autocompleter
id="languages"
href="%{remoteurl}"
delay="50"
loadMinimumCount="2"
/>
```

What I have is a situation where this `remoteurl` has to carry few additional parameters that are entered on the same page. How can I add those variables that jQuery makes a remote call using these additional parameters?

Or, is there a way to mention a function here in the tag so I can manage that request using function?

Comment: parameter from another textfield from same html page. That field is entered by User.

Comment: @Srini If you want to modify the jQuery code somehow to add addditional parameters in the url why do it on the server side?

Comment: @RomanC, actually my page has two fields.

SchoolId and student names

Student Names is an autocomplete field.

When SchoolID is entered, I want to make sure autocomplete for student name brings only student names.

I am trying to pass this additional parameter. 

Not trying to do anything at server side. If I can do it with additional javascript using client side.. that is also fine. I just will have manually map the field to my struts action class.

Comment: Yup, but the code you have tried is a JSP tag, doesn't matter if it generates javascript code, or HTML code, or both. Can you modify the template that used for doing it? Or you prefer to copy/paste generated code?

Comment: actually, by using server side i can use additional code like url builder that automatically takes care of webapp context (in struts). That way, my code is more migratable. If I do it on client side, I will have to do more coding. If it is feasible to do it quickly and easily using server side.. I would prefer. If not, then I would accept your recommendation and move my logic to use client side.

Comment: After further reacher and based on comments from @RomanC, I am moving to client side autocomplete rather than using Struts Jquery plugin.Thanks for advice.